# How to get Role Subscribe Users on Admin Menu only in Pages in Wordpress

Tags: wp-admin, homepage, wp-list-pages, users

How to get Role Subscribe Users on Admin Menu only in Pages in Wordpress and also asign pages to only a specific user and also get the pages on homepage by user ID.

Example:
here a link, i want to get all users by dropdown select option tag.
in Menu Pages -> Add New.
http://www.domainname.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=21&action=edit

here a link, i want to call pages on frontpages by user ID.
http://www.domainname.com/